# Не всегда работают регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Мне необходимо парсить страницы html.

Почему, некоторые данные удаётся достать, а некоторые нет?

К примеру:

```
r'<div class="a">(.+)</div>'  # работает

r'<strong class="b">(.+)</strong>'   # не работает
```

Comment: А пример "не работы" будет?

Comment: Не стоит парсить HTML регулярными выражениями. В общем случае этот инструмент не приспособлен для таких задач.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам посоветовал всё же использовать предназначенные для вашей задачи инструменты. lxml полностью покроет ваши потребности. В крайнем случае регулярными выражениями придётся пользоваться уже получив нужный блок из html страницы.
Ну или более специализированная под грабёж сайта библиотека (которая использует то-же самый lxml) - Grab (http://habrahabr.ru/post/127584/)

Answer (score 0):

Слишком расплывчатый вопрос, но попробуйте добавить «квантификатор жадности» `(.+?)`

Comment: пробовал ;(

Comment: Тогда нужно видеть, что есть, что из этого хочется получить (идеальный результат) и, что из этого получается сейчас (текущий результат).

Answer (score 0):

Точка в регулярном выражении - это любой символ, кроме переноса строки.
Если хотите, чтобы все символы захватывало, компилируйте регулярки с помощью флага re.DOTALL.